# Not standard Excel to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I've got a non-standard Excel table with the help of openpyxl. I've done some part on the way to convert it to pandas dataframe. But now I'm stuck with this problem.

I want to select just a range of columns rows and get data from them. Like take cells from 4 to 12 row, and column from j to x. I hope you understand me.

Sorry for my English.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', skiprows=4, usecols=['J:X'], nrows=9)
```

If the number of rows is not fixed, you can use your second column as delimiter.

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', skiprows=4, usecols=['J:X'])
df = df[df.iloc[:, 1].notna()]
```

Comment: thank you for answering me , i ve done this with help openpyxl  , pandas does not suit me because table not square and there is a lot of not relevant stuff , openpyxl supports absolute coordinates like cells =  sheet['J5:X12]

Comment: Can you post your solution as answer?

Answer (score 1):

you could skip the rows as you read the excel file to a Dataframe and initially drop the first 4 rows and then manipulate the Dataframe as follows.

- first line is reading the file by skipping the first 4 rows
- second line is dropping a range of rows from the dataframe (startRow and endRow being the integer values of the row index)
- third line is dropping 2 columns from the dataframe

```
df = pd.read_excel('fileName.xlsx', skiprows=4)
df.drop([startRow, endRow], inplace=True)
df.drop(['column1', 'column2'], axis=1)
```